# How to download a vue file as pdf file in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vue as below which I want to download as PDF when I click on a button in main_component. Please help me find a way around to do so.

download.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    This file includes a set of instructions to finish this process
  </div>
</template>
```

main_file.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    *Button to download the above file as PDF*
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Javascript [window.print](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp) document method and import your **download.vue** component into **main_file.vue** component and then pass the **innerHTML** of download.vue component by using $refs.

**Method 1: Save as PDF without any plugin.**

Here is the code snippet that will give you a dialog of print, where you can print or save PDF.

**main_file.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="printDownload">Print Download</button>
    <Download v-show="false" ref="DownloadComp" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Download from './Download'
  export default {
    components: {
      Download,
    },
    methods: {
      printDownload () {
          let w = window.open()
          w.document.write(this.$refs.DownloadComp.$el.innerHTML)
          w.document.close()
          w.setTimeout(function () {
            w.print()
          }, 1000)
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

**Method 2: Generate PDF of Any Component with CSS:**
To generate pdf and auto-download with all inner HTML and CSS, use the [VueHtml2pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-html2pdf) npm package; it has many customization options and can help you download your component into PDF.

Here is working example with your code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="downloadPDF">Print Download</button>
    <VueHtml2pdf :manual-pagination="true" :enable-download="true" ref="DownloadComp">
      <section slot="pdf-content">
            <Download />
        </section>
    </VueHtml2pdf>
    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueHtml2pdf from 'vue-html2pdf'
import Download from './Download'
export default {
  components: {
    Download,
    VueHtml2pdf
  },
  methods: {
    downloadPDF () {
        this.$refs.DownloadComp.generatePdf()
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Actually I want the file to download automatically on clicking the button

Comment: @user12763413 please check my anwser, is exactly what you want, no extra libs needs.

Comment: @RiyazKhan I am able to download the file but the css styles are not applied to the downloaded PDF

Comment: @user12763413 updated method 2, it will use the CSS inside the component and generate the pdf.

Comment: @RiyazKhan it downloads the file, shows the styles but it cuts the text. Doesn't show entire text on the page.

Comment: @user12763413 apply some padding to the div.

Comment: @RiyazKhan can you please tell me how to pass URL like (http://example.com/about) in here so this page can be downloadable as pdf. URL i want to pass like same domain or intranet site...

Answer (score 2):

You need a component to download any file from any URL, so, for this case, we can create a component to accomplish this objective, we can use fetch API (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```
<template>
  <button @mousedown="downloadFile">Download File</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["file", "name"],
  methods: {
    downloadFile() {
      const me = this;
      fetch(me.file)
        .then((resp) => resp.blob())
        .then((blob) => {
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          const a = document.createElement("a");
          a.style.display = "none";
          a.href = url;
          // the filename you want
          a.download = me.name || "file.json";
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.click();
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
          alert("your file has downloaded!"); // or you know, something with better UX...
        })
        .catch(() => alert("oh no!"));
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Now, in some component we calle it in this way:

```
<template>
  <download-button :file="file" name="myFilename.json" />
</template>

<script>
import DownloadButton from "./DownloadButton";
export default {
  name: "SomeComponent",
  components: {
    DownloadButton,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      file: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
    };
  },
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
};
</script>
```

Just change the URL for your PDF and the name.

**UPDATE**: To download AS PDF some section of your DOM you can use html2pdf.js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2pdf.js)

So, in this case, you need to adapt your component like this:

```
<template>
  <button @mousedown="downloadFile">Download File</button>
</template>

<script>
import html2pdf from "html2pdf.js";

export default {
  props: ["dom", "name"],
  methods: {
    downloadFile() {
      const me = this;

      const invoice = document.querySelector(me.dom);
      var opt = {
        margin: 1,
        filename: me.name,
      };
      html2pdf().from(invoice).set(opt).save();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

And in some component you can call it in this way:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center mt-50 mb-50">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-right mb-3">
          <download-button
            class="btn btn-primary"
            dom="#invoice"
            name="myFilename.pdf"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="card" id="invoice">
            <div class="card-header bg-transparent header-elements-inline">
              <h6 class="card-title text-primary">Sale invoice</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="mb-4 pull-left">
                    <ul class="list list-unstyled mb-0 text-left">
                      <li>2269 Six Sigma</li>
                      <li>New york city</li>
                      <li>+1 474 44737 47</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="mb-4">
                    <div class="text-sm-right">
                      <h4 class="invoice-color mb-2 mt-md-2">
                        Invoice #BBB1243
                      </h4>
                      <ul class="list list-unstyled mb-0">
                        <li>
                          Date:
                          <span class="font-weight-semibold"
                            >March 15, 2020</span
                          >
                        </li>
                        <li>
                          Due date:
                          <span class="font-weight-semibold"
                            >March 30, 2020</span
                          >
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="d-md-flex flex-md-wrap">
                <div class="mb-4 mb-md-2 text-left">
                  <span class="text-muted">Invoice To:</span>
                  <ul class="list list-unstyled mb-0">
                    <li>
                      <h5 class="my-2">Tibco Turang</h5>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <span class="font-weight-semibold"
                        >Samantha Mutual funds Ltd</span
                      >
                    </li>
                    <li>Gurung Street</li>
                    <li>23 BB Lane</li>
                    <li>Hong kong</li>
                    <li>234 456 5678</li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-abc="true">tibco@samantha.com</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-2 ml-auto">
                  <span class="text-muted">Payment Details:</span>
                  <div class="d-flex flex-wrap wmin-md-400">
                    <ul class="list list-unstyled mb-0 text-left">
                      <li>
                        <h5 class="my-2">Total Due:</h5>
                      </li>
                      <li>Bank name:</li>
                      <li>Country:</li>
                      <li>City:</li>
                      <li>Address:</li>
                      <li>IBAN:</li>
                      <li>SWIFT code:</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="list list-unstyled text-right mb-0 ml-auto">
                      <li>
                        <h5 class="font-weight-semibold my-2">$1,090</h5>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <span class="font-weight-semibold">Hong Kong Bank</span>
                      </li>
                      <li>Hong Kong</li>
                      <li>Thurnung street, 21</li>
                      <li>New standard</li>
                      <li>
                        <span class="font-weight-semibold">98574959485</span>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <span class="font-weight-semibold">BHDHD98273BER</span>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-lg">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Rate</th>
                    <th>Hours</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <h6 class="mb-0">Arts and design template</h6>
                      <span class="text-muted"
                        >in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
                        eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Duis aute irure dolor in
                        reprehenderit</span
                      >
                    </td>
                    <td>$120</td>
                    <td>180</td>
                    <td><span class="font-weight-semibold">$300</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <h6 class="mb-0">Template for desnging the arts</h6>
                      <span class="text-muted"
                        >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
                        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</span
                      >
                    </td>
                    <td>$140</td>
                    <td>100</td>
                    <td><span class="font-weight-semibold">$240</span></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <h6 class="mb-0">Technical support international</h6>
                      <span class="text-muted"
                        >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
                        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor</span
                      >
                    </td>
                    <td>$250</td>
                    <td>$250</td>
                    <td><span class="font-weight-semibold">$500</span></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="d-md-flex flex-md-wrap">
                <div class="pt-2 mb-3 wmin-md-400 ml-auto">
                  <h6 class="mb-3 text-left">Total due</h6>
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <th class="text-left">Subtotal:</th>
                          <td class="text-right">$1,090</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <th class="text-left">
                            Tax: <span class="font-weight-normal">(25%)</span>
                          </th>
                          <td class="text-right">$27</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <th class="text-left">Total:</th>
                          <td class="text-right text-primary">
                            <h5 class="font-weight-semibold">$1,160</h5>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="text-right mt-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                      <b><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o mr-1"></i></b> Send
                      invoice
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
              <span class="text-muted"
                >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
                enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
                nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor in
                reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
                nulla pariatur.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit</span
              >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import DownloadButton from "./DownloadButton";
export default {
  name: "SomeComponent",
  components: {
    DownloadButton,
  },
};
</script>
```

You can check how it works here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-meadow-m5k67?file=/src/components/DownloadButton.vue:0-429

Comment: @user12763413 I have modified my answer to accomplish your question, now you can download any part of your html/DOM as PDF, please check, thanks.

Comment: In my case,  I have the button to download the file on another page and file to download is different. So how can I define the url for that file to be downloaded?

Comment: I have tried by providing URL into that ... My web page written in vue template syntax so it is taking index.html not the URL's one. Is there any work around for vue page based on URL